# The value of local variable temp is not used

Tags: java

Here the value of local variable *temp* is not used. This code was done in Eclipse:

```
int temp = n;

while(n > 0) {      
   r = n % 10;      
   temp = n / 10;

   if(r!= 0 && r!= 1) {
       ...
    ...
```

Comment: Yes. it is not used. What's your question?

Comment: If you remove every line that uses `temp` your program doesn't change. Why would you put it in there in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The `temp` variable not used, it's only assigned. Since it's not used, it can be eliminated. It's only considered to be used if you have code that access its value and does something with it.

However, it's just a warning, though it might indicate that you forgot to write the code that accesses this variable, or that you don't need this variable at all.